# pip install makes ValueError: invalid literal

Tags: pip, windows-10, installation, registry, valueerror

While I was trying to install pytorch or something else with pip (ex: `pip install -U pip`), pip started to create following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

  File "c:\users\xahha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 60, in proxy_bypass_registry
    proxyEnable = int(winreg.QueryValueEx(internetSettings,
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I ran the command with `cmd` but it also occurs when I try to install pytorch via conda. I think it's kind of registry problem as I can see `winreg` at error message. But I don't have any idea what should I do.

I'm currently using Windows 10, and haven't touched any registry setting.

I checked the source code of that file(python38\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests\utils.py)

I found this comment in line 60:
`# ProxyEnable could be REG_SZ or REG_DWORD, normalizing it`

but when I checked my registry, it was REG_BINARY with the value '00 00 00 00'.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using 32 bit python? Also what are you trying to achieve with `pip install -U pip`?

Comment: Hmm I thought I had downloaded 64bit but it was not- that was my fault. The first command I typed was `pip install torch===1.4.0 torchvision===0.5.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` and after that I just try to test whether pip works fine or not.

Sadly uninstalling 32bit and re-installing 64bit doesn't change the matter.

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured in your internet settings?

Comment: Try changing the value to `REG_DWORD`, that is what I have in my system

Comment: Thanks! It works! I delete the `REG_BINARY` key then I add `REG_DWORD`.